# abstract gettting array value or null if empty

Tags: php, arrays, design-patterns, null, abstraction

It's common that I need `NULL` when an array key/index is not set, so I was thinking about abstracting out `isset(...) ? ... : ...;` into a function like:

```php
function valueOrNull($array,$key){
    return isset($array[$key]) 
            ? $array[$key] : NULL;
}
```

Then I would call it as:

```php
$somePerson->id = valueOrNull($data, 'id');
```

---

Then `$somePerson->id` would be `NULL`, in the case of a `$_POST` request to create a new person, whereas when loading from the database, it would have the id as an int.

Is this a good idea? Am I being too lazy? I just hate typing `$array['key']`, so typing  it twice is extra annoying.

And what about the naming `valueOrNull`? Is this a clear enough name? Is it too verbose?

Lastly, is there a briefer syntax than the ternary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since php7 there's a [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) with which your codes can be reduced to:

```
$somePerson->id = $data ?? null;
// also works for arrays:
$somePerson->id = $data['id'] ?? null;
```

Comment: heckin yeah! Thanks! I came across this once a month or two ago, I think... and I guess I didn't read it or I forgot, maybe. So much nicer than the isset ternary and no need for abstracting to a function.